# Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using wso2 Integration Studio and I have an OAuth configured endpoint in Integration. When I Just export project artifacts and run the Integration (In Micro Integrator) It works without any issue (Integrated Endpoint test completes without any issue). Then I created a Docker Image and Created a container using this image. When I test the integrated endpoint this time I get the below error in the docker container logs.

ERROR {OAuthConfiguredHTTPEndpoint} - Could not generate access token for oauth configured http endpoint PublicEP org.apache.synapse.endpoints.oauth.OAuthException: Error while accessing the Token URL. HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

But the same test was completed previously as I mentioned earlier without any issues.

Can you please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the MI side, it would be helpful to compare the wire logs [1] between the successful and error scenarios.
2. Can the container connect with the Token service? Try nslookup  and ping  to confirm.
3. Does the Token Service show any errors and does it return the 400 response?

[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/micro-integrator/classic-observability-logs/configuring-log4j2-properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs

Comment: 1.I will try with the logs.
2.Yes the Container can connect with the token service.
3.Token services gives error in the backend with Auth failed and it returns a 400 bad request error response.

Hope this information can help you isolate the problem

Comment: Hi I still could not resolve this issue. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Did you check if there are any differences between the successful and unsuccessful token requests?